# Why gives the error "Missing '}'.?

Tags: command-line, bash, tcsh

I am using the ubuntu under Windows. I had changed the login shell from `bash` to `tcsh`. After adding some PATH env into the /etc/profile , I need to `source` the profile. I ran

```
source /etc/profile
```

But it gives

```
Missing '}'.
```

even after I removed the adding PATH command line. I think this is an error, isn't it? I want to fix it.
Now my `/etc/profile` is like following, could you help me to figure out why this happen?

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
~
~
```

Comment: tcsh is not  a Bourne compatible shell, it uses different syntax, so feeding it the .profile bash script will fail.

Comment: @ubfan1 thank you for your advice. I think I should create some .cshrc file.